# Thread Safe Synchronization Block

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have some confusion regarding **thread Synchronization**. Consider i have two thread **Thread1** and **Thread2** and two method **synchronized foo1()** and **foo2()**. foo1() is **synchronized** method and foo2() is not, in foo1 internally there is a statement which calls foo2() and if Thread1 calls foo1() and in that it is working in foo2() method, at the same time Thread2 want to access foo2() method directly which is not synchronized.

So my question is 
will Thread2 get access of Foo2()? or it will wait for Thread1 to complete its task?

Comment: It is recommended to post a short code snippet whenever you can, to illustrate / reproduce your problem precisely.

Comment: Yes i do follow these instruction, Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the object, not the method which is locked.  This means you can have the two threads in foo1() if they are accessing different objects.  If they are accessing the same object, the same lock will prevent concurrent access regardless of what is called first or what calls it.

BTW: foo1() can call itself as it already has the lock.

Comment: A source of confusion is that the method is labelled as synchronized but its is not the method which is locked. ;)

Comment: To expand on Peter Lawrey's comment, `public synchronized void foo() {...}` really means `public void foo() { synchronized(this) {...} }`

Comment: @Anonymoose, `s/synrhconized/synchronized/`

Answer (score 4):

If `foo2()` is not synchronized, any thread can call it any time without being blocked. It doesn't make any difference whether a thread is calling it from another method which is itself synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Thread2 won't be blocked and won't wait. 
It will start execution Foo2, since it's not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Thread2 can call foo2() directly,because foo2() not a synchronized method,so any thread can call it and not acquire the current object's monitor。